# Checking if class is of certain type

Tags: java, class, generics

I'm trying to create a method inside a class that will take `Class` as a parameter and will check if the current object is of that type. The code i have:

```
public class MyEvent extends MyBPMNNode {

public boolean isKindOf(Class<?> node) {
    boolean b = MyEvent.this instanceof node;
    return b;
}
```

But i compile it it gives me:

```
Error:(9, 45) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class node
```

What am i doing wrong here? Maybe my understanding of the '`Class`' class is not right.

Comment: `node.isAssignableFrom(this)`. `instanceof` requires a compile-time constant second operand.

Comment: Correction: `instanceof` requires a *reference type* as the second operand.

Comment: @AndyTurner: `.isAssignableFrom()` takes a `Class`. `this` is not a `Class`

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
public boolean isKindOf(Class<?> clazz) {
    return clazz.isInstance(this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're probably after `node.isAssignableFrom(MyEvent.this)`.

Answer (score -2):

You are introducing generics for no particular reason. Try this:

```
    public boolean isKindOf(Object node) {
        // weak
        return node.getClass().isAssignableFrom(getClass());
        // stronger, but not appropriate in your case
        //return this.getClass().equals(node.getClass());
    }
```

Andy Turner's answer is much more concise. Pardon me.